# Properties of logs. Why does the log of a power, does the exponent become a coefficient?

Tags: logarithms

I'm having trouble seeing number 3 clearly. Or rather, I'm having trouble seeing a proof. I've tested a series of numbers and it works, but I'm having trouble seeing why. Can anyone clarify?

[image]

Here is where I get confused:

I start with this log:

$$ \log_2 4^1 = 2$$

now if I raise both sides to the 2nd power then:

$$ \log_2 4^{1^2} = 2^2$$
$$ = \log_2 4^2 = 4$$
$$ = 2 \cdot \log_2 4 = 4$$

but if I raise both sides to the power of 1.5 then:
$$ \log_2 4^{2 \cdot 1.5} \ne 4^{1.5} \ne 8$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that using property $1$, we have $$\begin{align}\log_a(x^y)&=\log_a(\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots\cdot x}_{y\,\text{times}})\\&=\underbrace{\log_a(x)+\log_a(x)+\cdots+\log_a(x)}_{y\,\text{times}}\\&=y\log_a(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: What happens if $y$ is non-integer?

Answer (score 2):

By definition:
$$
a^{\log_a x}=x
$$

Now, if:
$$
\log_a (x^y)=\alpha
$$
we have
$$
a^\alpha=x^y =\left( a^{\log_a x}\right)^y = a^{y\log_a x}
$$
so
$$
\alpha=y\log_a x
$$

Comment: how does that last line follow? I think I get everything up until the last line.

Comment: In the real field $a^\alpha=a^\beta \iff \alpha=\beta$. So, from $a^\alpha= a^{y\log_a x}$....